RP2040 board layout
I have laid out three different boards for the RP2040. The first worked without a hitch. The second won't work at all, even with an external clock source connected to XIN. Windows occasionally reports that "a device has malfunctioned and is not recognized" when I plug it in. The third only works with an external clock source connected. All three designs were fabricated on 4 layer boards, stacked in the order signal-ground-power-signal.
Design 1:

Design 2:

Design 3:

The only obvious differences I see are in the USB connector grounding:
Design 1 floats the connector ground pin and bonds the shell to board ground.
Design 2 bonds the connector ground pin to board ground but leaves the shell floating. (I tried adding a jumper between the shell and the RP2040 ground pad on layer 4, without success)
Design 3 bonds both connector ground pin and connector shell to board ground.
Designs 1 (C8 and C12) and 2 (C10 and C11) use 1uF decoupling caps. Design 3 uses 2.2uF (C9, C10, C25). All other decoupling caps are 100nF.
In each case I tried to follow the official hardware design guide. I used the recommended crystal in design 1. For designs 2 and 3, I tried both the recommended crystal and a ABM8G-12.000MHZ-4Y-T3 without success.
It seems that I've improperly laid out the oscillator section in designs 2 and 3, but I don't see the difference to design 1. There must additionally be other things wrong with design 2, since it won't run even with an external clock.
What did I do wrong?

The layer underneath the data trace is the ground plane.
I focus on USB and clock because they are the most difficult for me to debug: either USB works or it doesn't.
I couldn't directly scope the oscillator: I only have 1x/10x probes and I think I measured ~1.5V at XIN but no oscillation.
I measured 3.3V and 1.1V in the correct places with both a multimeter and oscilloscope, so unless there are transients occurring when I'm not watching, I don't suspect the power supply.
